# Laravel Middleware Does not work in routes

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

i have problem with laravel's (5.5) middlewares. Firstly, i created a middleware called AdminPanelAuth

Thats my middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AdminPanelAuth
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
}
```

and registered to Kernel.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminPanelAuth::class,
    'auth.basic' => 
\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => 
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class           
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,           
    'throttle' =>     
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

And i put that new admin middleware to my route file,

```
Route::group(
[
    'namespace'  => 'Backpack\Base\app\Http\Controllers',
    'middleware' => ['web', 'admin'],
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix'),
],
function () {
...
};
```

Admin middleware does not work for my routes. I've been tried to put this in web.php but nothings changed, still not working for me.

ps. i allready use composer dump-autoload, php artisan clear:compiled and php artisan optimize.

Thanks for your helps, best regards!

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Have you modified the `web` middleware group and is `StartSession::class` being used?

Comment: @NikolaGavric Laravel 5.5

Comment: @btl middlewares working normal, my just admin middleware doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try separating `web` middleware from `admin` like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix')], function () {
      ...
      Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
         ...
      });
      ...
};
```

**EDIT:**

In your middleware add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

And in your `Kernel`, add `admin` middleware you created under `throttle`

**EDIT 2:**

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\AdminPanelAuth::class, //Make sure your middleware is last in array
    ],
    ...
]
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => config('backpack.base.route_prefix')], function () {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Not worked, i think i make somethings wrong in my kernel

Comment: Can you at least dump something inside of your `admin middleware` so you can confirm that the request is hitting the middleware?

Comment: request not hitting the middleware

Comment: Can you include your `admin middleware` code inside of your question

Comment: Check the updated answer and if it still doesn't work, post your updated code and try checking if the request hits your middleware by `dd('HIT');` in your `handle` method of your `middleware`

Comment: Not hitting :((

Comment: Try the code here https://paste.laravel.io/7402943a-3bf6-488e-94cc-4e5feb7b2a4c and tell me what happens

Comment: I fixed my problem with adding the admin array after the web array in middlewareGroups, thanks for your helps!